# Tasks in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, task

I have an application (Spring 4 MVC+ JPA + MySQL+Maven integration example using annotations) , integrating Spring with Hibernate using annotation based configuration; and I want to create a task in order to use it in the controller

Having this task:

```
@Configurable
public class SMSSenderTask implements Runnable {

    protected static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SMSSenderTask.class);

    @Autowired
    SMSSender smsService;

    private String msg;

    private String to;

    public SMSSenderTask(String msg, String to) {
        super();
        this.msg = msg;
        this.to = to;
    }



    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            smsService.sendSMS(msg, to);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

and this other one

```
public class SMSSenderTaskExecutor {

    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

     @Autowired
     SMSSender smsService;

     @Autowired
      public SMSSenderTaskExecutor(TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
      }

     public void sendSMS(String msg, String to) {
          taskExecutor.execute(new SMSSenderTask (msg, to));
     }

}
```

--

I put this piece of code in the controller but I got a NullpointerException

```
SMSSenderTask smsSenderTask = new SMSSenderTask ("ddd", "33473664038");
smsSenderTask.run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When u use the new statement to construct a task object.U autowired service smsService hasn't been initialized yet. So when u invoke the run method, when the execution comes to smsService.sendSMS(msg, to); , the program throws a null pointerException.

U can put a SmsService as a constructor parameter to ur code to avoid that happen.